# Overlapping memory with sprintf(snprintf)

Tags: c++, printf, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

Edit: What about if we had this

```
char value_arr[8];    
// value_arr is set to some value
snprintf(value_arr, 8, "%d", *value_arr);
```

is this behavior defined?

---

Let's say for some ungainly reason I have

```
char value_arr[8];
// value_arr is set to some value
int* value_i = reinterpret_cast<int*>(value_arr);

snprintf(value_arr, 8, "%d", *value_i); // the behaviour in question
```

Is there a guarantee that, for example, if `*value_i` = 7, then `value_arr` will take on the value of "7". Is this behavior defined? Such that `value_i` is first dereferenced, then passed by value, and then formatted, then stored into the array.

Normally, the value of `*value_i` can be expected to not change, but storing the string into `value_arr` violates that.

It seems to function as expected when I test it, but I can't seem to find a definitive answer in the documentation. The function signature has `...`, which to my knowledge has something to do with `va_list`, but I'm afraid I'm not very knowledgable on the workings of variadic functions.

```
int sprintf (char* str, const char* format, ... );
```

Comment: Probably an XY problem.

Comment: Probably not an XY problem, since I was pretty much asking for curiosity's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the original code, evaluating the expression `*value_i` causes undefined behaviour by violating the strict aliasing rule. It is not permitted to alias a char array as `int`.

For the edited code, `snprintf(value_arr, 8, "%d", *value_arr);`, it is fine and will format the character code of the first character in the array. Evaluation of function arguments is sequenced-before entering the function. (C++17 intro.execution/11)

Comment: Isn't the cast itself already a problem due to different alignment restrictions?

Comment: @Deduplicator If it's not correctly aligned then the result of the cast is unspecified

Comment: "Evaluation of function arguments is sequenced-before entering the function." To clarify, is this C++17 only?

Comment: @ChilliDoughnuts it's always been that way, I just used the latest standard for paragraph number reference. In earlier standards the sequencing of the arguments and postfix-expression amongst each other was less strict, but there was always a sequence point on function entry

Comment: @M.M Ah ok I see, and so `snprintf(value_arr, 8, "%s othertext", value_arr)` would then be undefined from @Karlinde's answer, yes? Since in this case it would pass the pointer value.

Comment: @ChilliDoughnuts yes, that usage is undefined behavior, since you are writing new data to the same memory address that you are reading data from.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behaviour; You use a pointer of type `int*` to point to an object of type `char[8]` with different / relaxed alignment requirements compared to `int*`. Dereferencing this pointer then yields UB.

Answer (score 1):

The following can be found at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf:

> If a call to sprintf or snprintf causes copying to take place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

I would interpret your example to fall into this case and as such it would be classified as Undefined Behaviour, according to this page.

Edit: Some more details at https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf:

> Some programs imprudently rely on code such as the following
>
> sprintf(buf, "%s some further text", buf);
>
> to append text to buf. However, the standards explicitly note that the results are undefined if source and destination buffers overlap when calling sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), and vsnprintf(). Depending on the version of gcc(1) used, and the compiler options employed, calls such as the above will not produce the expected results.

Comment: The parameters to `snprintf` are evaluated before the call, and as it is a `%d` and a `*value_i`, it is call-by-value; so no overlap in my opinion.