# Coverity issue: Copy of overlapping memory (OVERLAPPING_COPY) on sprintf statement

Tags: c++, memory-management, printf, coverity, memory-corruption

```
char arr[512];
...
sprintf(arr, "%s %30s", arr, "Some Text");
```

I'm getting the following message for the sprintf statement:
In the call to function sprintf, the arguments arr and arr may point to the same object.

Is there another way to implement this kind of formatting?

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016983/overlapping-memory-with-sprintfsnprintf)

Comment: Yeah but it wasn't too clear. I gather it might be undefined behaviour. So how would I fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that code? Without context, it looks buggy.

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf): "If a call to sprintf or snprintf causes copying to take place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined". You're also missing an argument.

Comment: The warning you get is a good reminder to drop `sprintf` and use C++ iostreams or a library like [fmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) or [Boost.Format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/format/doc/format.html).

Answer (score 2):

The overlapping warning has to do with the fact that you are copying `arr` to itself, thus overwriting it's content.

Furthermore in the code:

```
sprintf(arr, "%s %0x", arr);
                  ^^^
```

`%s` takes the `arr` string, but `%0x` doesn't take an unsigned hexadecimal integer variable as it should, so you are probably missing a parameter.

Something along the lines of:

```
char arr[512];
char arr2[1024];
unsigned int x = 15;
sprintf(arr2, "%s %0x", arr, x);
```

Answer (score 2):

This code code contains two unrelated errors. As for the PVS-Studio analyzer, it issues two following warnings:

- V576 Incorrect format. A different number of actual arguments is expected while calling 'sprintf' function. Expected: 4. Present: 3. test.cpp 54
- V541 It is dangerous to print the 'arr' string into itself. test.cpp 54

The first one implies that the function is passed insufficient number of actual arguments. Indeed, the format string indicates that a string and an integer number are expected as arguments. But only a string is passed. There is no numeric argument, resulting in the usage of an amount of memory with a random value and consequently undefined behavior.

The second warning tells us that there is no guarantee that the `sprintf` function works correctly if one buffer is used as an input and output buffer. Such code might work correctly or it might not. It all depends on the implementation of the `sprintf` function. In any case, there is no reason to write code in such a way.

Therefore, Coverity is absolutely right when issuing the warning for this code. The code is definitely incorrect.

P.S. It reminded me of another funny case related to the usage of a "[fake sprintf](https://www.viva64.com/en/b/0535/)" :).